# Want to dual boot: Windows 8.1 / Ubuntu 13.10, but can't boot from flash drive and hard drive is reported as "full"

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, hard-drive, multi-boot, operating-systems

1. PC won't boot "bootable" flash drives.
2. Hard drive is "full" and "140TB".

⠀**Goal:** Dual boot Windows 8.1 / Ubuntu 13.10, have functional hard drive

Question may {contain, miss} (ir)relevant information because I am inexperienced with Linux, partitioning and boot processes. If you need information or clarification, I will fetch it and explain.

---

Computer: Acer Aspire 5734Z
OS: Mint 15 with Cinnamon desktop environment 
I own copies of Windows 7 and Windows 8.1

---

- Ran Windows 7, no problems
- Removed Windows 7
- Installed Mint 15
- Removed Mint 15
- Tried installing Manjaro

  - Foolish repartitioning upon prompt: Removed all partitions, allocate all resources to a single new partition. Can't remember the settings.
  - Stuck in boot loop with GRUB, couldn't boot from flash drive
- Service desk at University got PC out of boot loop
- Installed Mint 15 from flash drive

  - Repartitioned according to Mint 15 default settings (may misremember)
- Run functional Mint 15, but can't boot from flash drives (A)
- Deleted personal files by human error
- Recovered files with photoRec until hard drive was full. (B)
- Deleted majority of recovered files

I can't remember if 140TB claim appeared after (A) or (B).

---

When I try booting from flash drive, this happens:

- Select boot from flash drive
- Void screen
- If I do nothing, then Mint 15 boots
- Else if I push any key, this menu appears:

  GNU GRUB version 2.00-13ubuntu3

  ```
  Linux Mint 15 Cinnamon 64-bit, 3.8.0-19-generic (/dev/sda1)
  Linux Mint 15 Cinnamon 64-bit, 3.8.0-19-generic (/dev/sda1) -- recovery mode
  Memory test (memtest86+)
  Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)
  ```

Example is Ubuntu attempt. I've also tried Windows 7, Windows 8.1, Manjaro0.8, Mint 15 and Ubuntu 13.10 through SSD and USBs of different formats.

---

See screenshots below. gParted and the file browser conflict on hard drive size numbers. If it is true that I have used 92% of hard drive space as implied by gParted, then something has gone wrong while I tried to delete recovered files. Note that hidden files are not shown in the file system/root view, despite having enabled "View Hidden Files". However hidden files are visible when I do not access as root.

[image: Screenshot_from_2013_11_27_18_45_06]

Comment: anything I touch breaks down; I tried updating the image that other user inlined, but now it doesn't show. maybe because of lacking reputation?

Comment: Will re-add. Note that in most cases you can undo an edit by clicking on the "edited X min ago [by username]" and then using the revert option.

Comment: How did you prepare flash drives from which you are trying to install Windows? Looks like these drives are not bootable in the legacy BIOS mode for some reason (and UEFI mode would require using the GPT partition table format instead of MBR). The partition table itself should not prevent the Windows installation wizard from starting (but it won't find any usable space for installation — you need to make some free space for Windows partitions using gParted).

Comment: The free space mismatch (23.33 GiB vs 9.2 GB) is most likely due to some space reserved for root (the running system does not report that space as available, because regular users would not be able to use it, but gParted reports the actual free space). The completely unreasonable used size reported by the file manager is most likely due to counting some files from virtual filesystems such as `/proc` and `/sys`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reformated USB to ntfs, then Ubuntu would install. My lack of experience stopped me from achieveing this earlier. Tried same with Win7, but no luck. I am quite certain this has to do with fundamental GRUB / Windows booting conflicts which I will seek solutions to when I have the time.

Problem 1) is halfways solved, 2) is fully solved. Because such a large part of this Question's foundation now is irrelevant, I am declaring this Question to be Answered.

Thank you all for your input.

Answer (score -1):

> How do I achieve this?

I should be able to shed light on the reason why you might **not** be able to achieve this, which will hopefully give you direction.

The problem I had was that Windows 8 needed UEFI to boot, but 99% of Linux distributions don't work with UEFI. If I set my laptop back to 'legacy' BIOS mode, Linux would boot but Windows 8 wouldn't.

The only combination that worked for me was Windows 8 / Ubuntu 13 because, controversially, Canonical have paid to have Ubuntu's bootloader 'signed'...

I might not have the story completely correct but I remember being outraged that I could no longer just boot whatever I wanted on my new 'Windows 8' machine

Comment: Does this mean that the new question for me to ask is: 
"How do I install UEFI in such a way that I can install win8 or win7 from flash drive immediately after?"
?

Comment: In general, Windows 7 and Windows 8 do not require UEFI to boot (and 32-bit versions of those systems do not support UEFI at all). However, 64-bit Windows versions **preinstalled by OEM on recent computers** usually are installed in UEFI mode (and in case of Windows 8, Secure Boot is enabled by default, which is what prevents booting of any OS without a properly signed bootloader). In this case the user usually does not receive a real Windows installation media, and has no easy and supported way to switch to the legacy BIOS mode while keeping the OEM Windows license.

Comment: @Jobbo - Ubuntu has no problem supporting UEFI.  This answer is incorrect.

Comment: @Ramhound Thats what i'm saying in the answer.. most linux distros don't support UEFI, Ubuntu does..

Comment: Who cares about other distros the author wants to use Ubuntu...